# C++ What does return function do after if statements in loop?-Prime Test

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int prime(int n)
{
    int i;
    if (n == 1) return 0;  // zero- not prime
    if (n == 2) return 1;  // one- prime
    for (i = 2; i <= ceil(sqrt(n)); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) return 0; // remainder is zero
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long n;
    while (cin >> n) {
        cout << prime(n) << endl;
    }
}
```

I know that 0 means not prime and 1 means prime. Can someone please explain how are all the return functions used to accomplish this?

Why not use `cout << "0"` for not prime and `cout << "1"` for prime?

Comment: The return type of prime() is int. Hence it returns an integer. You can call this function from elsewhere and check the value it returns. Depending on the return value, you can take respective actions :)

Comment: You could have checked the formatting of your post before hitting 'submit', mate.

Comment: One-time freebie fix. Next time I downvote!!

Comment: It would be clearer to return a bool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could `cout` directly from the function. That would be valid.

But when you make a mathematical function, it's more conventional to `return` its value, so that the code that called it can then do whatever it likes. It can `cout` it, or save it to a variable, or perform other calculations.

If the function directly `cout`ed the result, then you're stuck: it can only do that one thing with the result. That's limiting, and for no benefit.